# Java 8 Stream throwing exception about Stream being closed

Tags: java

I have this code below that is throwing `stream has already been operated upon or closed`

```
    private static void readDataInputFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    List<String> rowList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Stream<String> inputStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        Optional<String> headerOptional = inputStream.findFirst();
        String header = headerOptional.get();
        int headerColumnCount = header.split(Constants.SEPERATOR_ESCAPED).length;
        rowList = inputStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (String string : rowList) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know we can't reuse the stream. I used the stream at `inputStream.findFirst();` as well as at `inputStream.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

What do I do in this case? Should I create another stream or is there a way to  copy the stream?

Comment: Why don't you just check for the first line in the collected list?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : I can do `rowList.get(0)` . however I'd like to understand the solution to this exception

Comment: This question is now closed, here's my answer:

Since you need to read all the rows, I would recommend getting the lines in a `List` and modifying it instead of going with `Stream`.

https://gist.github.com/GuiSim/a7170a69440383721a1d3b34c9922b2e